# Discontigous nested namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a project in which Nested namespace is required but these namespace will be spread over multiple headers.

```
//BaseDeclaration.h
namespace Base_NS
{
namespace Element_NS{};
namespace StockItem_NS{};
}
```

This is the structure of my Base Header.

Now I want to use Element_NS in Element.h or StockItem_NS in StockItem.h
What is the best way to use these discontiguous nested namespaces.

```
//Element.h
namespace Base_NS{
namespace Element_NS{
int data;
}
}

or 

namespace Element_NS{
int data;
}
```

Or is there any other appropriate of handling this type of cases.

Thanks

Comment: Only the first case. The second one defines ::Element_NS which is unrelated to ::Base_NS::Element_NS.

Answer (score 4):

Until c++17:

```
namespace Base_NS{
  namespace Element_NS{
    int data;
  }
}
```

Since c++17:

```
namespace Base_NS::Element_NS {
  int data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not declare empty namespaces in the BaseDeclaration.h file.

There are two approaches to write code in shared namespaces. First is a simple one, you just write namespaces each time when it necessary, like you mentioned above.

```
namespace Base_NS {
namespace Element_NS {
    int data;
}
}
```

Or you can define macros (the BaseDeclaration.h file is good place for it)

```
#define BEGIN_ELEMENT_NS 
    namespace Base_NS { \
    namespace Element_NS {

#define END_ELEMENT_NS }}
```

And use it instead

```
BEGIN_ELEMENT_NS
    int data;
END_ELEMENT_NS
```

Second approach is used in some libraries like Qt and Boost. After all, second approach allows to avoid typos in namespace names.